# My PHP and jQuery code submits blank data to the database

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

I've tried everything to fix it, from changing the id attr names (wasn't sure if there was a collision anywhere) to rewriting it. Not too sure what else to troubleshoot, so I figured I'd ask the stack community.

My HTML code

```
<input type="hidden" id="quizid" value="Module 1" name="quizid">
<input type="hidden" id="quizby" value="Jordan" name="quizby">
<input type="hidden" id="monescore" value="" name="monescore">
```

The "monescore" updates at the end of the quiz with JS.

My PHP code

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "testing123", "quiz");

    $quiz_id = $_POST['quizid'];
    $quiz_by = $_POST['quizby'];
    $quiz_score = $_POST['monescore'];
    $addScore = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO quiz_scores (quiz_id, quiz_by, quiz_score) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($addScore, "sss", $quiz_id, $quiz_by, $quiz_score);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($addScore);

    mysqli_stmt_close($addScore);
```

and finally my jQuery / AJAX code...

```
var quiz_id = $('#quizid').val();
                var quiz_by = $('#quizby').val();
                var quiz_score = $('#monescore').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "handlers/quiz-post.php",
                    data: {
                        quiz_id: quiz_id,
                        quiz_by: quiz_by,
                        quiz_score: quiz_score
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('success');
                    }
                });
```

This is what my database shows;

[image]

Comment: _"Not too sure what else to troubleshoot"_ - for starters: Check what request actually gets send using your browser dev tools, make a debug output of what $_POST contains on the receiving end.

Comment: At what point in the lifecycle are `quiz_id`, `quiz_by`, and `quiz_score` set in your JavaScript/jQuery code? Looks like you're trying to obtain the values before they've been set, and are sending blank values instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the PHP file, when you send the information to the server via Ajax, the parameters have different names than what you receive in php.

for example from ajax, the parameter is called quiz_id but in php you receive it as $_POST['quizid'], you should receive it as $_POST['quiz_id']

Answer (score -1):

The best way to debug this is to check the data values of the quiz_id, quiz_value and quiz_score variables throughout your code.

Step 1:
`console.log()` each of the variables in the `jQuery` and check if they contain the data.

Step 2:
`var_dump` or `print_r` them in PHP to see the values and datatypes of each of the variables - the result of the PHP should come as response text on the jQuery.

If the data is available check in the your database data types, length limits and other settings to see if they are satisfied by the variables being passed. If that still doesn't work, I would recommend using PHP Data Objects (PDO) to see if this can send the data successfully.

Another quick reminder, check if the database connection was successful.

Comment: "*Another quick reminder, check if the database connection was successful.*" In what scenario would a database connection *not* be successful if the script is writing rows to the database?

Comment: Just making sure, sometimes stuff with computers can get crazy

Comment: @Mosesmadale no, it doesn't. Computers are relentlessly logical and do exactly what they're told, they cannot act outside their instructions. The only thing that goes crazy is the programmers when they can't work out what wrong thing they told the computer to do. Everything a computer does is completely predictable as long as you know how to look :-). But this is good advice mostly, apart from  the random database connection suggestion

Comment: Appreciate your help Moses - I know sometimes people on this site can get a full of themselves when they answer questions like this.